# How to customize a collection of objects in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-collection

I want to fetch rows from a database, cast them in an array, and then add a custom row so that I can pass the whole thing to a view (Blade file). I've tried using `->push()` but I can't seem to get the format of the arrays to match. The below code sample gets rows with the user's id, name, and location.

```
$profiles = \App\Profiles::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

From here, I want to append "distance" to each entry in the collection. I want customized information fetched from the database so that I can pass it seamlessly to a view (Blade file).

Answer (score 0):

`$profiles` is an Eloquent collection, not an array.

```
$profiles = Profiles::latest()->get();

foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
   $profile->distance = 'your value';
}

return view('profile', compact('profiles');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array and insert data as below:

```
$profiles = \App\Profiles::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

foreach ($profiles as &$profile) { // loop by reference so it will update current array
   $profile->distance = "Your Value";
}
```

Then you can pass this array to your view. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You get a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections) instance, so why don't you use one of its useful methods? In this case [Map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map):

> ### [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map)
>
> The `map` method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the
>   item and return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items:
>
> ```php
> $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
>
> $multiplied = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
>     return $item * 2;
> });
>
> $multiplied->all();
>
> // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
> ```

So in your case:

```php
$profiles = \App\Profiles::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

$profiles->map(function ($profile) {
    $profile->distance = 'your value';

    return $profile;
});


// Then return it to your view
return view('profiles')->withProfiles('profiles'));
```

Of course, you can inline all this:

```php
$profiles = \App\Profiles
                ::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get()
                ->map(function($profile) {
                    $profile->distance = 'your value';

                    return $profile;
                });

// Then return it to your view
return view('profiles')->withProfiles('profiles'));
```

You said:

> I basically want info from the database and my customized info in one
>   array so that I can pass it easily to a view.

If your desired is to custom/format your data to return it to your view, why noy use [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)? Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) of the documentation.